# Is it possible to convert individual assignment to group assignment programmatically via Okta API?

Tags: okta, okta-api

An Okta Admin is able to convert individual assignments to group assignments as stated in the [help documentation](https://help.okta.com/en/prod/Content/Topics/Provisioning/lcm/lcm-convert-user-group.htm). Is it possible to do this in a programmatic way through the Okta API? I'm not able to find any reference in the [docs](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/).

Comment: As answered by Philipp, this feature is not available via Okta API. I opened and idea through the Okta hep center. If you feel this is worth to have, please vote. Thanks :)

https://ideas.okta.com/app/#/case/153064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no way to do that through API, as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

I utilize Okta workflows to programmatically convert individual assignments to group assignments. You can send a POST (I use the custom API action card in Okta Workflows, but I'm sure you could post directly to the API) to `/api/v1/apps/<okta app ID>/users/<okta userID>` with the following body: `{"scope":"GROUP"}`. Hope that helps, I know I struggled to find a solution until I discovered this method.